How to fill hole in mesh cleanly
i'm trying to model a crankset, I have left a ref picture but when I want to connect 4 extruded groups of faces I can't seem to get a clean mesh to fill the hole. I'm quite new to modelling so any help is appreciated, I know i'm just not thinking with blender logic i'm certain there's an obvious solution.
Much love,
Dan



I quickly modeled something similar to yours.


Connect the geometry to get an edge loop around the hole you want to fill.


You should also delete these faces


select the edge loop, press Ctrl F and select Grid fill


change the grid fill settings until you get something you like.




Thanks very much
